# Java 8 stream api code to add a element to a List based on condition keeping the list size same

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider i have below list

```
List<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<>(); 
          list=Arrays.asList(0,1,2,0,4,10);
          
          alist.addAll(list);
```

I want the output as 0 0 1 2 0 0.

That means if there is a zero in the list add one more zero in list. Do this untill the size of list is same as input size.

How can this be done using Java 8 stream api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
alist.stream()
    .flatMap(i -> i == 0 ? Stream.of(i, 0) : Stream.of(i))
    .limit(alist.size())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This basically:

1. flatmaps your integer to a stream of itself if non-zero, and a stream of itself and an additional zero if equal to zero
2. limits the size of your list to the original size

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 16+ can also do it using `mapMulti` which allows one to replace items in the stream with zero or more elements.

```
List<Integer> alist = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,0,4,10);
```

- In this case, `mapMulti` simply accepts the current value and
- then adds another `0` if the current value is `0`.

```
alist = alist.stream().<Integer>mapMulti((i, consumer) -> {
    consumer.accept(i);
    if (i == 0) {
        consumer.accept(0);
    }
}).limit(alist.size()).toList();

System.out.println(alist);
```

prints

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```